# Behaviour of children() and find() when using :first

Tags: jquery

I'm a little bit confused by the behaviour when using `children()` and `find()` with `:first`.

Consider the following markup:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

From what I understand, the following should return the same collection of elements, as there are no grandchildren (which is the only difference stated between `find()` and `children()` in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/)).

However, if I add a class to the first `.child`, the results are different:

```
$('.parent').find('.child:first').addClass('active');
```

Results in the following markup:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="child active">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="child active">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

When doing the same thing using the `children()` method, I get:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="child active">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Why?

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/d4zytr7z/)

Comment: Well, now I'm curious how you can come up with this issue ? Haha..

Comment: Look at http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.children and http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question!

#### TL;DR

The difference is that `find` searches individually starting from each wrapped element and then aggregates the results, while `children` gets a single aggregate pool of candidate results which are then filtered based on the specified selector. This results in selectors like `:first` giving a different result if the original jQuery object wraps more than one element.

The reason for this is understandable (`children` knows from the get-go that all of its possible matches share a very important property in the DOM, so it makes sense to narrow down the candidate list up front for performance reasons), but IMO you can't call the result anything else than a bug in the current implementation.

#### `$.fn.find`

`find` produces two matches like that because it runs a search on each of the wrapped elements of the current jQuery object and *then* aggregates the results. So for each `.parent` we match the first descendant in document order that is a `.child`.

Here's the source:

```
function (selector) {
    var i, ret = [],
        self = this,
        len = self.length;

    if (typeof selector !== "string") {
        return this.pushStack(jQuery(selector).filter(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (jQuery.contains(self[i], this)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        jQuery.find(selector, self[i], ret);   // ** IMPORTANT **
    }

    // Needed because $( selector, context ) becomes $( context ).find(selector)
    ret = this.pushStack(len > 1 ? jQuery.unique(ret) : ret);
    ret.selector = this.selector ? this.selector + " " + selector : selector;
    return ret;
}
```

Everything happens in the line marked "IMPORTANT": `jQuery.find` is an alias to [`Sizzle`](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#-public-api), which *appends* its results to `ret` each time. Obviously if you do `.find(":first")` on a jQuery object that wraps N elements with each element having at least one descendant, you will get back exactly N results.

#### `$.fn.children`

`children` takes another route: for each wrapped element it traverses the DOM to get hold of its children, and then filters the results *as a whole* based on the selector. Obviously in this case this would leave at most one element as the final result.

Here's how it happens:

```
function (until, selector) {
    var ret = jQuery.map(this, fn, until); // ** IMPORTANT 1 **

    if (name.slice(-5) !== "Until") {
        selector = until;
    }

    if (selector && typeof selector === "string") {
        ret = jQuery.filter(selector, ret); // ** IMPORTANT 2 **
    }

    if (this.length > 1) {
        // Remove duplicates
        if (!guaranteedUnique[name]) {
            ret = jQuery.unique(ret);
        }

        // Reverse order for parents* and prev-derivatives
        if (rparentsprev.test(name)) {
            ret = ret.reverse();
        }
    }

    return this.pushStack(ret);
}
```

This is not as self-explanatory because the code is shared with a bunch of methods that do structural traversal of the DOM (`parent`, `next`, `prev`, `siblings`, etc), but again the relevant part of the code is very simple: The line "IMPORTANT 1" collects the results of the structural traversal ("get the children") inside `ret`, and those results as a whole are filtered based on the selector (`".child:first"`). This will finally leave at most one result.

Answer (score -1):

```
    The children() method returns all direct children of the selected element.
    The find() method returns descendant elements of the selected element.
please check below links for that

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp
```

Answer (score -2):

Quote from [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

`The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.`

That would explain why `.children()` only put active class on 1 of them while `.find()` goes through everything

Comment: This clearly states that the .children() method only travels a single level down the DOM tree. No, I did not link james padolsey's masterpiece, but I didn't think I had to in order to understand. Thanks.